# How to open Instagram 'link in bio' url in Chrome and not in Instagram Browser (React)

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, browser, safari, instagram

In a React website I'm working on, I'm trying to open the website url from instagram link in bio in Chrome (or Safari in case of iOS) but it's not working. It always open the site using Instagram browser.
I've found some quite old solutions but none of them worked.

The React version is:
`"react": "^18.2.0",

Have you faced this issue? Any information is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

I try to open a website url from link in bio.
I expected the website open in Chrome.
The website opens in Instagram browser.